# Storing a date in .property and comparing with current date

Tags: java, date

How do I store a future date in a .property file and compare this date with current the current date?

Answer (score 8):

You could:

1. save a formatted date
2. if you want, save the format too, adding flexibility

The property file:

```
myDate=25/01/2012
myDate.pattern=dd/MM/yyyy
```

Then, in your program you could load the date this way:

```
// choose one of two lines!
String pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy"; // for a fixed format
String pattern = propertyFile.getProperty("myDate.pattern");

String formattedDate = propertyFile.getProperty("myDate");
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
Date myDate = format.parse(formattedDate);
```

**Edit**: to compare to current...

```
1. boolean isFuture = myDate.after(new Date())
2. boolean isPast = myDate.before(new Date())
3. int compare = myDate.compareTo(new Date());
// compare < 0 => before
// compare == 0 => equal
// compare > 0 => after
```

Comment: Adding the pattern to the properties file, allows changing it without changing the code. By example you could include hours and minutes, or specifying a timezone.

Answer (score 3):

Well, there are a few things to consider here:

- Do you genuinely only care about the *date*, or is it the date and time?
- Does the time zone matter? Are you interested in a future *instant*, or a future local time?
- Should the properties file be human readable?

If you're just dealing with an instant and you don't care about anyone being able to understand which instant it is from the properties file, I'd be tempted to store the string representation of a `long` (i.e. the millis in a `java.util.Date`) and then to check it, just parse the string and compare the result with `System.currentTimeMillis`. It avoids the whole messy formatting and parsing of dates and times.

For anything more complicated, I'd thoroughly recommend using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) which will make it easier to understand what concepts you're really dealing with (e.g. `LocalDate`, `LocalTime` or `DateTime`) and which has better formatting and parsing support (IMO) than the JDK.