# Storing date in .properties file java

Tags: java, properties

I am trying to store a date in my config.properties file however the format is wrong.

```
try{
    prop.setProperty("last_run_time",sdf.format(date));
    prop.store(new FileOutputStream("config.properties"),null);
}
catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The value of `sdf.format(date))` is correct e.g. `2013-08-23 02:47` . Issue is that in the properties file `2013-08-23 02\:47` gets stored. Where does the `'\'` come from?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243954/storing-a-date-in-property-and-comparing-with-current-date

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\` unmask your `:`. Normaly the `:` is used to define a key with a value! You can read more about unmasking and the .properties file [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties).

Comment: The `=` is used to define key/value pairs, not the `:`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Both will work. You can use `key:value` instead of `key=value`. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load(java.io.Reader)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name isn't it possible to use a `space`, `=` or `:`??

Comment: @Gerret Yes, both `=` and `:` work the same way, and if none of those is used then the key is the character sequence until the first whitespace.

Comment: @JonSkeet: you live and learn ;) Thanks for the info, I have never seen the colon being used for that though.

Answer (score 2):

This is from the Java Doc:

> The key contains all of the characters in the line starting with the
>   first non-white space character and up to, but not including, the
>   first unescaped '=', ':', or white space character other than a line
>   terminator. All of these key termination characters may be included in
>   the key by escaping them with a preceding backslash character; for
>   example,
>
> \:\=
>
> would be the two-character key ":=". Line terminator characters can be
>   included using \r and \n escape sequences. Any white space after the
>   key is skipped; if the first non-white space character after the key
>   is '=' or ':', then it is ignored and any white space characters after
>   it are also skipped. All remaining characters on the line become part
>   of the associated element string; if there are no remaining
>   characters, the element is the empty string "". Once the raw character
>   sequences constituting the key and element are identified, escape
>   processing is performed as described above.

I think it is fine to save like \:

The Java property file is not a text for you to read. It is for the Java code to read. The escaping `\` will ensure that the next time it is read by your Java app, it will be interpreted as a colon, not as a key/value separator.

Answer (score 0):

The **colon** is one of the possible **key/value** separation characters. The **leading backslash escapes** it (this is only necessary when the key contains a colon, but you're more on the save side when always escaping it).

Variants of valid assignments:

```
key value
key= value
key: value
```

See [Javadoc: Properties.load(Reader)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.Reader%29)